# Can we relate the character of the permutation representation of $G$ on the cosets $G/\langle g_i\rangle$ to the number of cycles of $g_i$?

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory, symmetric-groups, characters

Let $G$ be a finite group of order $n$ generated by permutations $g_1,\dots,g_s$ such that $g_1g_2\cdots g_s$ is the identity permutation.

Consider the permutation representation obtained by embedding $G$ into $S_n$. Can we relate the character of the permutation representation of $G$ on the cosets $G/\langle g_i\rangle$ to the number of cycles of $g_i$?

The character of the permutation representation of $G$ on the cosets $G/\langle g_i\rangle$ equals the number of points of $G/\langle g_i\rangle$ fixed by $g_i$, but I'm not sure how to think about this. I believe that the quotient makes it different from just the number of 1-cycles that $g_i$ has, but I'm not sure how to go about computing this character.

I am also wondering if there are embeddings that this might be easier for. Is there a permutation representation of $G$ that we can choose so that there is a "nice" relationship between the character of the permutation representation of $G$ on the cosets $G/\langle g_i\rangle$ to the number of cycles of $g_i$?

Comment: So secretly $G$ is a subgroup of a symmetric group $S_n$? It seems the answer would depend on which embedding you choose into $S_n$. For example, if $\phi\colon G\to S_n$ is an embedding, then $(\phi,\phi)\colon G\to S_n\times S_n\subset S_{2n}$ is also a valid embedding, which would change all the cycle types.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Let's let $|G|=n$ and embed $G$ in $S_n$. (Since in general it's hard to find the smallest permutation group isomorphic to $G$.) I have edited the question.

Comment: To your point, it could also be true that some embeddings give a more straightforward relationship between the character on the cosets $G/\langle g_i\rangle$ and the number of cycles of $g_i$.